# Rails - Save parameters between actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that books spaces for certain dates. In the index page, I have a search form to display only the spaces that are available from **params[:query1]** to **params[:query2]** certain dates. Then in the space show page, I have a form for booking the space.

I'd like to maintain the **params[:query1]** and **params[:query2]** also in the space show page as the default value for the booking form.

## index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag spaces_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline" do %>
  <%= label_tag :query1, "Check in" %>
  <%= date_field_tag :query1, params[:query1], class: "form-control" %>
  <%= label_tag :query2, "Check out" %>
  <%= date_field_tag :query2, params[:query2], class: "form-control" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

## show.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: [@space, @booking], local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :check_in, "Check in" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_in, value: params[:query1], class: "form-control" %>
  <%= label_tag :check_out, "Check out" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_out, value: params[:query2], class: "form-control" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reserve", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Whats your problem? whats the error?

Comment: Can we see your controller code? Want to confirm what you are doing with the params there.

Comment: The problem is that I can't reuse the query params as a default value for the booking form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a session to store your queries and use them throughout your app. You can store your queries in a session in your index action like this:

```
def index
  session[:query1] = params[:query1]
  session[:query2] = params[:query2]
end
```

Then in your show action, you can access the session like this:

```
def show
  @query1 = session[:query1]
  @query2 = session[:query2]
end
```

In your form on your show page, you can then use the instance variables:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@space, @booking], local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :check_in, "Check in" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_in, value: @query1, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= label_tag :check_out, "Check out" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_out, value: @query2, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reserve", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Learn more about [session](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)